# Correct use of IDisposable pattern when using Managed C++ wrapper in C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, unmanaged, idisposable

My C# class creates and uses Managed C++ object that wraps (allocates and uses) unmanaged C++ objects and resources. The Managed C++ class correctly implements IDisposable with Destructor and Finalizer. Therefore, it appears that my C# class should also implement IDisposable. I want to follow correct IDisposable pattern in C# as well.

The following is unclear to me:

- Within Dispose method of my C# class, should I treat my Managed C++ objects as managed or unmanaged (since they rely on unmanaged resources internally)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your C# class should implement IDisposable as well.  Its Dispose() method should simply dispose the C++/CLI objects.  No need for a finalizer, you already implemented one in your wrappers.  Your wrappers are no different from many other .NET classes that wrap an operating system resource.

For example:

```
class Test : IDisposable {
    private CppWrapper obj;
    //...
    public void Dispose() {
       if (obj != null) { 
           obj.Dispose();
           obj = null;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, please clarify. If the following is my C# code, in which section A or B should I dispose of my managed C++ classes?         class Test : IDisposable
   {
     private bool isDisposed = false;
   
     ~Test() {Dispose(false);}
   
     protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
       if (disposing)  {
         // Section A. Dispose the managed resources
       }
       // Section B. Dispose the un-managed resources
       isDisposed = true;
     }
   
     public void Dispose()
     {
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
     }
   }

Comment: No, there is no need for this pattern since you don't have a finalizer.  Thus no need to call GC.SuppressFinalize() and Dispose can never be called with *disposing* set to false.  Which keeps it simple, I posted a snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans. However, I quote: "Finalize provides a backup to prevent resources from permanently leaking if the programmer fails to call Dispose". If so, why not have a Finalizer?

Comment: Because your C++/CLI class wrappers are the ones that own the unmanaged resource.  You gave them a finalizer.  That's enough to ensure that the unmanaged resource will always be released, even if the client programmer forgets to call Dispose() on your C# class.

Comment: OK, I understand now. Thank you once more Hans. Cheers.